# Function call passing incorrect number (C++ 11)

Tags: c++, function, c++11

I'm currently working on a project that is meant to teach the usage of functions in C++. I've worked with python in the path and have a reasonable understanding of functions in code (or so I thought) but for some reason I'm getting some alarming errors when I pass values through to my current function.

This is the entire code, my problem lies within the narc_num(153,3) call made in main. I added some cout statements into the narc_num function to see why I was getting wonky results and found that the num argument was getting passed as a completely different number. Why would this be?

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cmath> 
using std::cin; 
using std::cout; 
using std::endl; 

/* 
Function: order_parameters 
Purpose: If first is greater than second reassign the values so second is greater than first 
Algorithm: 
1.Pass arguments as references to first and second 
2.if statement that runs if first is greater than second 
3.within if statement switch values using a temporrary variable 
4.if else doesnt run nothing happens 
*/ 
void order_parameters(long & first,long & second)//passing long references of first and second 
{ 
 if(first > second)//start if when the ref to first > ref to second 
 { 
 long temp; // initialize temp 
 temp = second; //value temp is = to second 
 second = first; //second will now be first, temp is still = to first though as well 
 first = temp; //second is now set = to temp, which is first. dat swap 
 }//end if 
} 

/* 
Function: narc_num 
Purpose: check if a number is indeed a narcisstic number 
Algorithm: 
1.Pass num, the number to be checked, and power, the order the number will be checked against 
2.use a while loop to iterate through digits of number 
    -mod10 takes the last digit, the digit is raised to the power passed as an argument 
    -the value found is added to the total 
    -the number is then divided by 10 to remove the last digit, reiterates again. 
3.the total found by the while loop is checked against the number passed an as argument 
    -if the total is equal to the number it is narcisstic. 
*/ 
bool narc_num(long num, long power)// will return a boolean value, passing num and power integers 
{ 
//split all digits into seperate numbers, add together raised to power 
long total = 0,digit,num_copy; 
bool narc = false; //value to check if number is narcissitic or not 
num = num_copy; 
cout << "number"<< num << endl; 
while(num > 0) 
    {digit = num%10; 
     cout <<"digit" << digit << endl; 
     total += pow(digit,power); 
     cout <<"total" << total << endl; 
     num /= 10; //divides by 10 to go to the next digit down 
    } 
if (total == num) 
    narc = true; 
cout << total << endl; 
return narc; 
} 

long check_range(long first,long last,long power) 
{ 
bool check; 
order_parameters(first,last); //make sure parameters are in correct order 
for(first;first == last;first++);//iterate through all numbers from first to last 
  {check = narc_num(first,power); //check = True if narc number otherwise false 
   if (check == true) 
   {cout << first <<" is a narcissistic number of order " <<power<< endl; 
   }; 
   cout << "gothere"<< endl; 
   }; 
cout << "dick canoe"<< endl; 
} 

int main(){ 
narc_num(153,3); 
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to problem: `for(first;first == last;first++);` I guess you meant `!=` and the first `first` has no effect, you can write `for(;first != last;first++);`. `check_range` should also return something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the value of num_copy (an uninitialized long) to num near the top of the narc_num function. I believe you meant to assign num_copy the value of num. This is probably the cause of your unexpected results.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. When I print out num at the top it does not return 153 as expected but returned a cosiderably larger number. I have no clue why

Comment: @EricNewman Probably for the exact reason stated in the answer: you set `num` to an uninitialized value before printing it.

Comment: Oh god, I feel pretty stupid now. I couldnt even understand the help I was getting heh. Well thanks for all the help. Hopefuly I can finish this project quickly now.